# Whisper protocol: Version conflict between geth and ethereumj

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumj, whisper, shh

I am trying to use whisper in a permissioned network with both geth and ethereumj nodes. The Java nodes detect the capability shh version 2 of their geth peers, but only check for nodes with capability shh version 3 to add to the Whisper object's peer list. Thus the peer list remains empty and the Java nodes miss all Whisper messages.

Does ethereumj still support version 2 at all, does geth support or plan to support version 3?

Is there any way to configure ethereumj or geth to support different versions of the protocol? (Either client just seems to have an option to disable/enable whisper - the `--shh` command line option for geth, the `capabilities` option in ethereumj.conf - but no further whisper-related configuration options)

Comment: Whisper is a moving target currently. You might wish to get in touch with the status.im or augur.net developers which both use most recent versions of whisper.